# DB connection error while connecting through unix commands

Tags: oracle, unix

When I login to the unix db machine and run the command to connect to oracle database

```
sqlplus db_login_id/db_login_password.
```

I get error:

```
ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist
```

However I can connect to the server using TOAD...so the target definitely exists.
What should be my troubleshooting checklist

Comment: 1) ping the host, 2) check DNS settings, 3) check that the username doesn't need a fully qualified domain name (e.g. kaudshik@whatever.com vs kaudshik)

Comment: (3) is the cause. Thank you. Please post it in form of an answer so I can mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) ping the host, 2) check DNS settings, 3) check that the username doesn't need a fully qualified domain name (e.g. kaudshik@whatever.com vs kaudshik)